# LyX doesn't wrap underlined text

Tags: lyx

I'm using LyX 1.6.6.1 under Windows XP, and, as the title says, it doesn't wrap underlined text - i.e., the underlined text is "overflowing" outside of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you using to underline text? I'm guessing that it is something other than `\underbar{}` which doesn't affect the flow and wrapping. You can see the underlying TeX in LyX with View ➤ View Source.

Furthermore, in TeX generally, underlining should rarely be used as it is a convention of typewriters, not typesetters. Italics, font changes, even boxes are better ways to set off text in TeX. I'm also guessing that it was pretty hard to force LyX to underline and so you wound up accidentally forming an indivisible TeX `box` that - by definition - can't wrap.

LyX is pretty nifty for what it does, but it is only a wrapper for TeX and will likely produce more such mysteries when provoked. I'm not saying "learn TeX", I am suggesting that you become familiar with the 'real document' by keeping the source view open.

Comment: I used Ctrl+u to underline. How do I make LyX use underbar?

Comment: This current document is a prep case for a debate, should be read very quickly and therefore some sentences are underlined so they'll be noticed. How would you emphasize a certain sentence this way, using LyX?

Comment: Now I see it does use underbar, and it still does not wrap.

Comment: Tests have been done that show underlining **reduces** rapid readability as would any pixels that were not part of the letterforms. I'd use bold, font size increases, or font face changes in decreasing order of preference. as for your unbreakable underbar, show me the TeX code as an edit to your post above, I suspect there is something wrapped around it which makes a TeX box.

Comment: I accept your claim, changed to italics. Thanks.